# How to connect two span tags with Javascript using event propagation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className === "badge alert-info village"){
      const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.badge alert-info village');
      for (let i = 0; i < elementsToChange.length; i++) {
        const currentElement = elementsToChange[i];
        currentElement.innerText = event.target.innerText;
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
span.badge[contenteditable] {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.badge[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    display: inline-block;
}
span.badge[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
    content: attr(data-focused-advice);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, beatae!
      <span contenteditable="true" class="badge alert-info name" data-placeholder="Enter your name" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"></i>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, laboriosam?
      <span contenteditable="true" class="badge alert-info village" data-placeholder="Enter your village" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"></i>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, deleniti.
      <span contenteditable="true" class="badge alert-info name" data-placeholder="Enter your name" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"></i>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      <span contenteditable="true" class="badge alert-info village" data-placeholder="Enter your village" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span><i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"></i>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The desired behavior I was trying to achieve is that if the user enters her name at any of the span tags with the class "name" the others autocomplete but not the span tags with the class "village" and vice-versa.

This can be useful for forms in which the user needs to input her name at multiple places. Regardless of where she types it, all the others also update.

I thought this simply javascript function would do the trick but I am clearly missing something as it is not working.

Comment: If this is meant to be a form why aren't you using HTML5 `<form>` and `<input>` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close! First of all - change class selector in `const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.badge alert-info village');` to
`.badge.alert-info.village`. That way it can be found.
Second, a little tweak, when you run through the elements you need to change, you need to exclude the element that is currently being edited. If you don't do that, you'll get some funny results =)
I didn't do the `name` part as it should be the same as village except for the class names.

```
let item = document.querySelector('.test');

 item.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className === "badge alert-info village"){
      const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.badge.alert-info.village');
      for (let i = 0; i < elementsToChange.length; i++) {
        const currentElement = elementsToChange[i];
        if(currentElement != document.activeElement){ //excluding current element
            currentElement.innerText = event.target.innerText;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue! Could you please keep only the javascript in your answer? This helps keeping it more concise. I will then accept it :)

Comment: Hey, sure! I removed the snippet as It will work only with everything in it. 
But kept a separate code window with js =)